# Where are these white and blue buildings near water and cliffs?

Tags: identify-this, greece, architecture

Do you know this destination? If you know what it is, please tell me the name:

[image]

I saw it on a travel site (but it had no additional information). I'm impressed by the good weather, architecture and cliffs. The picture itself is great.

Comment: As @Geeo said, it's the island of Santorini, more specifically the town of Oia. I have been at the exact spot this picture was taken, and the architecture is so beautifully different I started feeling uncomfortable with all the bright buildings, still would love to go back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Google Image](https://www.google.it/search?tbs=sbi%3aAMhZZis3_1fhUeLyQ0xNzp7XA62-0F-z-AxWYoKhNX1eo_1L9iukjl2NMUbzMa10DzpWNKJUVxxAJmkJiXm1FNxTsDN1C60ZfACUpW18BfSExGGI87HFL78Jvs9npsJvW1BOlM8_1urgKJQvV7XqbjXeuL3PI3DgV2tisLd3omP5-Qj72rhM_1xqZ-yRjuNIgEVFyFlI6iENzvwmJdJeP3n8laX4mvvX-SIxOdcWUuRB3cAc4Iso3xq_1GcmSWtCw6D_1sMeCmTtuQDC3SGrUG1a69FPT0q3Pv-FtZAk7ozo7BV73kAlzHXvZi4SAHtXzwjXRoxrYFjpggJb2vPLVndUjPQVgAKE6-uPtmZc-iGyg2vxo63B2KI2lh6_19B6fhS1-5IMWgGWyBP0jJgpneDnwmkma5VyppFCp5-dcPTQbzCuMfGwdD-mTjEvKzmrv1nsaakZTZdQH9eZ1Mr7TOusI2if31a9Hr8xX138fGqj2NgB591Q6wG2Gfj2yVbKBvMdlMO-JuAKspgfHIeJOEBqE6N_1sAJXpsLRseXurI06x7RD4tMJ4bwKVZgUqv9mWx04TFSJJFC3-DoncWVPfaUikvMBJvfc4uXsqLG4kLnEo-_1sxJgP7NZzqp8iKJ18EG6Nid9lhALd0yLxDUasnMVt6M75qkKsZWtSReRYCfKN63x_1u71PQ5VEdi_1Y7BAOPykny9MrnVju22URMZrLdoZdn6rd530voxKLlsSfifeCWNu69msNoXQkfxp8l58WxaZacXzea8_1OLnO8rzMfh40yNBXRlb9k5G6VKX2jPccNWRBYjpe4DsvdgoTCshHmfHex3c5lrNpRjpyGoVg-0ywmFNXST559lTQemCand_13SVg-6F6WC20LqoAe57E4nVi_1TDAjGJnoBRfnwkRwiC6xLj5dFTVIbIYrdM38-uFctcJXmya5KIyHZ3SSPeqJpglbN9zaTVNXAkNSFlUXjNeAJmEObV9y7uoG1Xn4vTMbD4EtnqGOJbRcdwiA_1_1ER7VKTiRVq8iwl_1Q72O04BGMpH6jty5XZHHbDawmcfOj0FAt2CpWoPdQPhMioi7P5VWlEQglPWv_1b2RxGmgJEc43fV-veW7si0n1Fk68xjDzX9AU6349Au-RDLNyrxpB8yM9Q5Ne6DqjA8qXmoHXie_1gqc8qH1RUiy0YWalfIxFPBFRI4AqUQb7T3ziZgISwVVKnCVyNlLaYqiIZZyysIx-eaQQcse_18WDj2tr2a7jn3eVK5wg5N66Dm9xHlAugjEdpAy8wftExVNC4bxyeuYwr5L5ix99DvwtXhj5SOyeBkbur-vKYcN5TxPQviz7yDblf37WLpbqSFoJ7EFbQhtnQRfh3iNk431w5a3hh9zF7B-6DCk4kiohtpwNPqVm1OoXX-vDelEXOrcgBVLePB3LjxenG5peiytLWAGm7Nae8Q&hl=it&biw=1920&bih=961&site=imghp&sa=X&ei=Cx-FUpObIYXJhAfrgYHQAg&ved=0CFAQ9Q8oAA), it should be Santorini.

Comment: Haha, how could I forget to search by image. Thanks!

Comment: Are these roofs really in that color, naturally? Or is the image photo-edited?

Comment: @trejder they are painted

Answer (score 5):

It is Santorini.

Be sure to check the volcano and the red beach!